# Meaning of dF(x) when F is not continuous.

Tags: integration, probability-theory, derivatives, probability-distributions

I had been solving the following problem.

> Let F and G be two cumulative distribution functions on the real line. Show that if F and G have no common points of discontinuity in the interval [a, b], then:-
> $$ \int\limits_{x\in(a,b]}G(x)dF(x) = F(b)G(b) − F(a)G(a) − \int\limits_{x\in(a,b]} F(x)dG(x)$$

**My TRY**:- If G and F were "nice" then, I know this is a problem on by parts integration. But I am having hard time understanding that what is the meaning of $dF(x)$ when $F(x)$ is not continuous?
Also what does the phrase **if F and G have no common points of discontinuity in the interval [a, b]** mean here.

Comment: “if F and G have no common points of discontinuity” ...  Typically you’d think of $F$ and $G$, distribution functions as they are, to be continuous. But if you don’t, well you enter Riemann-Stieljes land. Break up your problem into regions and follow your intuition, which seems to be asking the right question.

Comment: you start very bad if you dont know what means $dF$. $dF$ is the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure induced by $F$. The result of the question is immediate from Tonelli's theorem.

Comment: Any discrete distribution gives an example of a discontinuous distribution function. For a simple one, let $X \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(1/2)$, such that $X = 0$ w.p. $1/2$ and $X = 1$ w.p. $1/2$. To calculate its expected value, we do $\mathbb{E}[X] = 0(1/2) + 1(1/2)$ -- in [Riemann-Stieltjes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral) land, we write $\mathbb{E}[X] = \int x \,\mathrm{d} F(x)$. If we think about where the discontinuities of $F$ are, this might provide some insight into the notation.